# authenthicate mgtwitterengine with username and password without webview

Tags: objective-c, mgtwitterengine

I am using Ben Gottlieb his implementation of MGTwitterEngine and OAuth (https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone).
When I use his implementation, I get a webview with a twitter loginscreen, and I have to login and grant the application.
Is it possible to do the authentication myself? So don't use the webview, but do it all in code, with username and password typed in a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using Twitter's xAuth authentication mechanism. This is however not as simple as you need to ask Twitter permission to use xAuth.