# Twitter login without webview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

In my app i have my own form for sign-in Twitter.
Is it possible login without standard webview (with popup from bottom) ??? I mean without framework which uses the most app from AppStore
Maybe some examples...

Thanks advance.

Comment: Perhaps see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473951/authenthicate-mgtwitterengine-with-username-and-password-without-webview

Comment: You probably could but it's done that way for security reasons. It's so they are giving their password to twitter and not to you. They have no idea what you may or may not do with it if they give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

All hail WWDC: [This is definitely what you want](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php#twitter-integration).  That is, if you will use new APIs.  This one only works with iOS 5.

Please remember to click the hollow check mark if this answer works for you.  **People are much more likely to answer your questions if you do.**